# Sending another Broadcast inside BroadcastReceiver not working?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

**Is it possible to send a broadcast from one `BroadcastReceiver` to another `BroadcastReceiver`s?**

I am running first broadcast receiver perfectly with below call:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(CalendarAlarmManager.ACTION_CHECK_NEXT_ALARM);
intent.setClass(context, CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver.class);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In first receiver, I'm doing some stuff and then running second broadcast receiver:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER);
intent.setClass(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);   // method is being called
```

Inside `AndroidManifest`:

```xml
        <receiver android:name=".CalendarProviderBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.SOMETHING.TEST" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.exmaple.SOMETHING.REMIND_ME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But surprisingly second receiver's `onReceive` method is not being called! Is ther any limitation in android for sending broadcast from another broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. There is no limitation in sending another broadcast from a broadcast.

I simply changed `AndroidManifest` from this:

```xml
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="false">  <--- This line is the problem
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.exmaple.SOMETHING.REMIND_ME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

to this:

```xml
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:exported="true">  <--- It is fixed now.
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.exmaple.SOMETHING.REMIND_ME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The problem with my code is that my broadcasts are defined inside a module other than **App module**. And maybe because of that, android is considering it as other application's receiver.